# PHP remove line break or CR LF with no success

Tags: php, preg-replace, line-breaks

I did a function to remove line break with php with no success, i tryed all replace code and i still get these line break, i create a json file and i can't read it from jsonp with jquery because of these line break seem to break it all.

```
function clean($text)
{
$text = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $text ) );  
$text = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/i", '', $text);
return $text;
}
```

When i look at the source, there some line break appening in all href, img and br
this is a json_encode output
example:

```
<a
href=\"http:\/\/example.com\/out\/content\/\" title=\"link to content website\">
```

line break afer a.
it's hapenig to img src and br

the only way i can remove these break it with

```
$text = preg_replace("/\s/i", '', $text);
```

But you understant that there's no space left in all the string and it's not what we want.

Comment: Thank's for all but until now, none of these solutions worked. But usually most of these solutions should work, but i don't understand why for my case it doesn't

Comment: The only way i found to fix it was
`$allcontent = preg_replace('/<img(.+?)src/ims', "imgsrc", $allcontent);`
and do find and replace imgsrc to <img src at the output

Comment: I hit the same and no solutions in this post worked for me. I found another similar post and this solution worked for me...hence posting it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3340510/405117

Answer (score 33):

this replace works better for me:

```
= str_replace (array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), ' ', $text)
```

Comment: As a note, in the case of e-mails and other MIME encodings, simply replacing `\r\n` (CRLF) with `\n` should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following

```
function clean($text)
{
    return trim(preg_replace("/(\s*[\r\n]+\s*|\s+)/", ' ', $text));
}
```

the first part `\s*[\r\n]+\s*` will replace any line breaks, it's leading spaces and it's tailing spaces into just one space.

the second part `\s+` will shrink spaces into one space.

then `trim()` removes the leading/tailing space.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
function clean($text)
{
    $parts = explode(' ', $text);
    foreach ($parts as $key => $value)
        $parts[$key] = preg_replace('/\s/', ' ', $value);
    return implode(' ', $parts);
}
```

Indeed, if instead of cleaning the JSON file like this, you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create it, you will get rid this problem in a previous step.

Comment: not working, i don't understand why with all these replace code my json output give me 14 line instead of one. my json output work on many domains and many host, but for this domain (Wordpress website) it give me line break

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the CRs and keep the LFs, it's really very simple (just common sense):

```
$text = str_replace("\r", "", $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use default trim function with  "character_mask".

For example:

```
$text = trim($text, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

Read the official documentation http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

Comment: This is default behaviour. Why would you explicitly state a default parameter value?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try walking the text character by character and call `ord()` on each, so you could see if these break characters are really `\r,\n`s?

Recently I got a similar problem with a whitespace which turned out to be a non-breakable space not even inside the ASCII table (ord code 194 or something).

If you are interested my solution was not to try and filter breaks, but to filter EVERYTHING except what was expected to be in text, like so:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^ \na-zа-я0-9`~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\-\=\[\]\{\}\\\|;\:'\",\.\/\<\>\?]+/ui", "", $text);
```

Comment: hi Tony, this did nothing for me

Answer (score 0):

use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) from the JSON extension to handle JSON de/serialization tasks:

```
$myobj = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'foz' => 'baz')

$json_myobj = json_encode($myobj);
echo $json_myobj;

$myobj = json_decode($json_myobj);
print_r($myobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

A method I use is `echo str_replace(array('\r\n', '\r', '\n', '\t'), array('\\r\\n', '\\r', '\\n', '\\t'), $text);`

What this does is allows you to see what characters are causing the breaks in the text, and replace them appropriately. For example, if you have a "\n" breaking your text, when you use this code, it will then display a "\n" in its place. Example:

```
<a
href=\"http:\/\/example.com\/out\/content\/\" title=\"link to content website\">
```

would become:

```
<a\n href=\"http:\/\/example.com\/out\/content\/\" title=\"link to content website\">
```

Naturally, there are a large amount of other breaking characters that could be used, but \r\n, \r, \n and \t are the ones most commonly used.

Comment: it's crazy but nothing apear.
by the way, the json_encode is called this way

`echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode(array('posts' => $posts)).')';`

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean($text)
{
    return trim(preg_replace('/\\\\r|\\\\n|\\\\t/i', ' ', $text));
}
```

Works fine.